# How to check why form is not valid

Tags: django, django-forms, validation

I have some troublesome form in my django app. Problem is that it doesn't validate. How can I check what is causing the problem ? I've tried the following :

```
form.data = {dictionary_with_data}  
form.is_valid()  
False  
form._errors  
{}  
form.errors  
{}  
Form.non_field_errors()  
[]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
form = YourForm(data={dict_with_data})
```